# Наполнение treeview объектами разных типов с использованием привязки

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем может быть ошибка при иерархическом постоении дерева с использованием HierarchicalDataTemplate.
После построения не заполняется внутренняя иерархия, хотелось бы понять по какой причине такое может происходить.

Код XAML:

```
        <TreeView x:Name="tvForLic">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Path = Consignee}" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding nameCustomer}" />
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding nameConsignee}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate.ItemTemplate>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
```

Класс Заказчик:

```
public partial class Customer
{
       [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Customer()
    {
        this.Consignee = new HashSet<Consignee>();
    }

    public int idCustomer { get; set; }
    public string nameCustomer { get; set; }
    public string legalAdrCustomer { get; set; }
    public string actualAdrCustomer { get; set; }
    public string innCustomer { get; set; }
    public string kppCustomer { get; set; }
    public string checkAcountCustomer { get; set; }
    public string corrAcountCustomer { get; set; }
    public string bikCustomer { get; set; }
    public string bankCustomer { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Consignee> Consignee { get; set; }
}
```

Класс Филиал:

```
public partial class Consignee
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Consignee()
    {
        this.Servers = new HashSet<Servers>();
        this.Systems = new HashSet<Systems>();
    }

    public int idConsignee { get; set; }
    public int idCustomerConsignee { get; set; }
    public string nameConsignee { get; set; }
    public string legalAdrConsignee { get; set; }
    public string actualAdrConsignee { get; set; }
    public string innConsignee { get; set; }

    public virtual Customer Customer { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Servers> Servers { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Systems> Systems { get; set; }
}
```

Код наполнения ItemsSourse запрашивает из БД весть список Заказчиков, возвращает список.

```
    using (var db = new Entities())
        {
           tvForLic.ItemsSource = db.Customer.ToList(); 
        }
```

Comment: а данные складываются в модели?

Comment: @VladimirT спасибо, навели на мысль проверить контект. Возможно немного топорно. но проблема решена, если  скорректировать код заполнения itemSourse. Осталось только разобрать причину, почему при удалении контекста, не заполняются дочерние сущности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В методе получения данных из таблицы БД (посредством EntityFramework) был использован контекст создаваемый в области using{}, переписав код следующим образом, ве дочерние сущности заполняются корректно.

```
   public static List<Customer> FillCustomerTest()
    {
        var _db = new LicMngrEntities();
            try
            { return _db.Customer.ToList(); }
            catch (Exception ex)
            { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); return null; }
    }
```